# Redirection of stdout and stderr to file not working on raspbian

Tags: stdout, raspbian, stderr, io-redirection

I am trying to redirect `STDOUT` and `STDERR` to a log file on raspberry pi.
My `.sh` script contains this line

```
sudo ./main.py &> client.log &
```

The script runs correctly as it transfers data to and from my server, but `client.log` file remains empty. I tried `&>`; `&>>`; `>>` with `2>&1`; and `|&`. None of them write any data to `client.log`.

```
sudo ./main.py
```

produces both `stdout` and `stderr` output. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you are looking for is:

```
sudo ./main.py > client.log 2>&1 &
```

- `> client.log`   redirects standard output to the file client.log
- `2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout
- `&` at the end of the line runs this in the background so you can continue working at the command prompt.

Note: if you log off while the background command is running, it will be killed.  You can override this behavior by adding `nohup` to the beginning of the line.  For more information google `bash jobs`

---

Edited to add additional information after comment below

revised syntax:

```
sudo stdbuf -o L -e L ./main.py > client.log 2>&1 &
```

- `stdbuf` modifies the default linux output buffering
- `-o L` Flushes stdout at the end of every line
- `-e L` Flushes stderr at the end of every line

Comment: It appears I was wrong... This solution as well as several others in my original post do write data to client.log, but they do so 15 minutes to several hours after it has been written to stdout/stderr by main.py, and the output tends to be cut off at arbitrary positions, i.e. in the middle of the line...

Answer (score 0):

python -u test.py > output.txt &
Python will buffer your output by default, and simply killing the script doesn't immediately flush that standard output to disk